# How to implement which button got clicked first,second and so on from random 10 buttons having random numbers

Tags: java, android

I have 10 buttons having 10 numbers from 1-10 at randomly arranged.Now i want to implement such a way in which if the first button clicked from 10 buttons at random will be having number 1 or else it will be blocked and so on for second button having number 2 and so...
i need help to get them implemented by code..help me with that code...thankyou

```
public void settingFirstPressedButton (int buttonPressed)
{
    if (firstPressedButton == -1)   //when firstPressedButton = -1 it means no button was pressed
      firstPressedButton = buttonPressed;
}
```

then:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(firstPressedButton==-1) {
            if(b1.getText()=="1") {
                b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                break;
            }
        } else {
            if(firstPressedButton==0) {
                if(b1.getText()=="2") {
                    b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                if(firstPressedButton==1){
                    if(b1.getText()=="3"){
                        b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    if(firstPressedButton==2){
                        if(b1.getText()=="4"){
                            b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                            break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(firstPressedButton==3){
                            if(b1.getText()=="5"){
                                b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                break;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if(firstPressedButton==4){
                                if(b1.getText()=="6"){
                                    b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                    break;
                                }
                            } else {
                                if(firstPressedButton==5){
                                    if(b1.getText()=="6"){
                                        b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    if(firstPressedButton==6){
                                        if(b1.getText()=="7"){
                                            b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                            break;
                                        }   
                                    } else {
                                        if(firstPressedButton==7){
                                            if(b1.getText()=="8"){
                                                b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                                break;
                                            } else {
                                                if(firstPressedButton==8){
                                                    if(b1.getText()=="9"){
                                                        b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                                        break;
                                                    }
                                                } else {
                                                    if(firstPressedButton==9){
                                                        if(b1.getText()=="10"){
                                                            b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                                            break;
```

Answer (score 2):

Oh man, it doesn't need to be this complicated.

```
// global variable
private int mCurrentNumber = 1;


// in onClick(...)
int numberPressed = Integer.parseInt(b1.getText())
if (numberPressed == mCurrentNumber) {
    b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    mCurrentNumber++;
}
```

Comment: You r telling me to add this method under which onclick?

Comment: Make your activity implement OnClickListener and set every button's onClickListener to `this`

Comment: Ok got that part...but for other buttons..its only for b1??

Comment: You can use 

    @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
    int numberPressed = Integer.parseInt(((Button) v).getText().toString());
    // Rest of code

for all buttons.